# Java-- do-while loop jumping to next iteration without checking exit condition?

Tags: java, do-while

I've coded a do-while for a method that reads from a text file, using BufferedReader. If you want the context, I'm doing to infamous text-based adventure game, and this method is extracting my game "items" from the text file so they can be made into objects in my HashMap.

Anyway, some of my descriptions have multiple lines, so I wanted to ensure that it would capture each line.

Here is the full chunk of code:

```
while ((currentLine = readerObject.readLine()) != null) {
     if (currentLine.startsWith("name: ")) {
          name = currentLine.substring(6);
     } else if (currentLine.startsWith("location: ")) {
          location = currentLine.substring(10);
     } else if (!currentLine.startsWith("DONE")) {
           do {
                if (currentLine.startsWith("description: ")) {
                     description = currentLine.substring(13);
                     currentLine = readerObject.readLine();
                } else { 
                     description = description.concat(currentLine);
                     currentLine = readerObject.readLine();
                }
           } while (!currentLine.startsWith("DONE"));
           itemsAll.put(name, new Items(name, location, description));
     }
}
```

This is the specific part of my code that is an issue:

```
do {
     if (currentLine.startsWith("description: ")) { 
           description = currentLine.substring(13);
           currentLine = readerObject.readLine();
     } else { 
           description = description.concat(currentLine);
           currentLine = readerObject.readLine();
     }
} while (!currentLine.startsWith("DONE"));
```

If the line that starts with "description: " is immediately followed by the line "DONE" then my intent is for the loop to exit when the exit condition is evaluated at the end of the first iteration. Instead, it's looping back into another iteration, so when it gets to the exit condition, it thinks that currentLine is null, and gives me this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.startsWith(String)" because "<local2>" is nullat TextInput.inputItems(TextInput.java:64)
```

I'm confused about why the do-while loop isn't exiting once currentLine is updated to DONE? I've already walked myself through it manually (determining what each value and output would be at every step) on paper and added in print statements to test where the issue is, but I just don't understand why.

I've figured out a more streamlined solution that works, but I feel like I'm missing something fundamental about why the original code isn't working... Can anyone explain?

Sorry if the reason is obvious... I've been coding for way too many hours today so my brain might be mush.

Comment: the implementation is not very *stable*. in the `else if` I would first check for `"description"` (instead of `! "DONE"`) and inside that `if` block loop while not `"DONE"`

Answer (score 1):

> I feel like I'm missing something fundamental about why the original
> code isn't working

What you are missing is that *You do not need another `do..while` loop*

All you need to do is:

- Read file line by line
- Save an `Item` if a line with "DONE" is found (Use `contains` instead of `startsWith()`, it's more intuitive and force user not to mix up "DONE" with other lines)
- save any other lines into your variables.

Sample:

```java
while ((currentLine = readerObject.readLine()) != null) {
    if (currentLine.contains("DONE")) { 
        itemsAll.put(name, new Items(name, location, description));
    }
    else if (currentLine.startsWith("name: ")) {
        name = currentLine.substring(6);
    }
    else if (currentLine.startsWith("location: ")) {
        location = currentLine.substring(10);
    }
    else if (currentLine.startsWith("description: ")) {
        description = currentLine.substring(13);
    } else {
        description = description.concat(currentLine);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing two things that can might have gone wrong:

1. Although the inner `do/while` ends, the top most `while` loop is still in execution. So, that is why your program is not exiting.
2. You need to do null check inside the `do/while` in the same manner as in the topmost `while` loop. Specifically, after you do: `currentLine = readerObject.readLine();`

Comment: Regarding your first point... if `currentLine` starts with "DONE", and the following line is `null`...

1. `do/while` exit condition met; `do/while` breaks
2. Execute `itemsAll.put(name, new Items(name, location, description));`
3. Return to start of outer `while` loop
4. Check condition (`currentLine = readerObject.readLine() != null`) moving readerObject to the next file line, which is `null`. 
5. `currentLine` is `null`, so condition not met. Break `while` loop before executing the code block inside.

That's how I _thought_ it would execute, what do I have wrong?

Comment: Please learn to debug the code using breakpoints. It is difficult to reason about the code just by looking at it, although it is a good skill to have.

Answer (score -1):

This is your `Record` model:

```java
@Getter
@Builder
public final class Record {

    private final String name;
    private final String location;
    private final String description;

}
```

This is how the main method looks like:

```java
Path file = Path.of("foo.txt");
List<Record> records = readRecords(file);
```

This is how you can read records from the file where where any parameter could have multiple lines:

```java
public static List<Record> readRecords(Path file) throws IOException {
    try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(file, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
        List<Record> records = new ArrayList<>();
        Queue<String> recordLines = new LinkedList<>();

        stream.forEach(line -> {
            if ("DONE".equalsIgnoreCase(line)) {
                if (!recordLines.isEmpty()) records.add(createRecord(recordLines));
            } else recordLines.add(line);
        });

        if (!recordLines.isEmpty()) records.add(createRecord(recordLines));

        return records.stream()
                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}

private static Record createRecord(Queue<String> recordLines) {
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

    while (!recordLines.isEmpty()) {
        Map.Entry<String, String> entry = readMultiLine(recordLines);
        if (!entry.getValue().isBlank()) map.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }

    return createRecords(map);
}

private static Map.Entry<String, String> readMultiLine(Queue<String> recordLines) {
    String marker = null;
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();

    while (!recordLines.isEmpty()) {
        String recordLine = recordLines.element();
        int pos = recordLine.indexOf(':');

        if (pos > 0) {
            if (marker != null) break;
            marker = recordLine.substring(0, pos);
        }

        buf.append(System.lineSeparator()).append(recordLine.substring(pos + 1));
        recordLines.remove();
    }

    return Map.entry(marker, buf.toString().trim());
}

private static Record createRecords(Map<String, String> map) {
    return Record.builder()
            .name(map.get("name"))
            .location(map.get("location"))
            .description(map.get("description"))
            .build();
}
```